# Timeout in Socket.Recieve

Tags: .net, sockets

I filched the following code from net to get GMT time from the site time-a.nist.gov. This code runs great but once in a blue moon it hangs. When I pause debugging the green arrow with the message "This is the next statement to execute when the thread returns from the current location"  shows next to s.Receive(ntpData);

```
        public static DateTime GetNetworkTime(IPEndPoint ep)
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                                  SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            s.Connect(ep);

            byte[] ntpData = new byte[48]; // RFC 2030
            ntpData[0] = 0x1B;
            for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++)
                ntpData[i] = 0;

            s.Send(ntpData);  
            s.Receive(ntpData);
            .
            .
       }
```

So I added the lines

```
 s.SendTimeout = 1000;
 s.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
```

Now it doesnt hang but throws the exception "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time"

StackTrace: at System.Net.Socket.Recieve(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,Int32, SocketFlags socketFlags)

Is this a server site (time-a.nist.gov) issue and hence no recourse except to call it again?

Also is there any way to handle this exception and call the GetNetworkTime method again.

I'd appreciate any help on this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Socket Timeouts only work when you are using the async versions of the Read and Write methods: BeginRead and BeginWrite. The synchronous versions will hang indefinitely or until the connection is terminated.

Comment: The code without timeouts hanged but when I added the Timeout code it at least stopped hanging and threw exception that I've shown in my OP.